# clojure.test/are with clojure.test/testing

Tags: unit-testing, clojure

In clojure.test there is a macro that allows to test several fixtures at the same time: [`are`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.test/are).

In clojure.test, is is possible to combine the `are` macro with `testing` ?

Ie. something like:

```
(are [scenario expected input]
  (testing scenario
    (= expected (my-fn input)))
    "scenario 1 - replaces -out by -in" "abc-out" "abc-in")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible with `are` in clojure.test..

I adjusted Stuart Sierra's [`are`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/2e0c0a9a89ede8221504edeb90e8c4ee6cce7e16/src/clj/clojure/test.clj#L571) to support `testing`'s scenario and failing message as follows:

```
(defmacro my-are
  [scenario fail-msg argv expr & args]
  (if (or
       (and (empty? argv) (empty? args))
       (and (pos? (count argv))
            (pos? (count args))
            (zero? (mod (count args) (count argv)))))
    `(testing ~scenario
       (clojure.template/do-template ~argv (is ~expr ~fail-msg) ~@args))
    (throw (IllegalArgumentException. "The number of args doesn't match are's argv."))))
```

Now the tests are wrapped in a `testing` scenario and fail-messaged are added.

This macro can be used like this:

```
(deftest my-test
  (my-are "Scenario 1: testing arithmetic" "Testing my stuff failed" 
          [x y] (= x y)
          2 (- 4 1)
          4 (* 2 2)
          5 (/ 10 2)))
```

This leads to:

> Test Summary
>   Tested 1 namespaces
>   Ran 3 assertions, in 1 test functions
>   1 failures
>   Results
>   1 non-passing tests:
>   Fail in my-test
>   Scenario 1: testing arithmetic
>   Testing my stuff failed
>   expected: (= 2 (- 4 1))
>   actual: (not (= 2 3))

You can see that the three assertions are executed, that the fail message ("Testing my stuff failed) is shown for the test that fails, and that the scenario message ("Scenario 1: testing arithmetic") is visible.

Comment: Stumbling on my own answer now, it would be nicer if a number of test cases within the are could be wrapped in multiple testing blocks, to differentiate them.